# How to know which subchild is updated in childChanged eventtype of realtime firebase in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assuming My Firebase RealTime Database has the child name Users which further has sub-child which are emails like this "christianLiz@gmail.com", the sub-child emails further have sub-child called name, age, and country.

I added an observeEvent on child changed the snippets looks like this.

```
 ref.child("USERS").child("christianLiz@gmail,com").observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.exists(){
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            if value!["name"] != nil{
                print("here")
            }else{
                print("not here")
            }

    }){ (error) in
        print("")
    }
```

When i test after changing the value of country the app crashes and cause is this value!["name"]. Now i do know that the childChanged event is only returning the child which is changed in my testing scenario "country" so other values are notin snapshot but i want to check which one is updated name or age or country. How can i modify the code above to achieve this.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to reconsider using email addresses as node names. What happens if the email address changes? Not only will you have to read in, delete and write out a new node with the new email address (remember - node keys cannot be changed), you'll have to do that at *every node that references this node*. Use .childByAutoId to create your node names. Also, you won't have to parse the email addresses for special chars either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hasChild` to check if a child exists or not:

```
if snapshot.hasChild("country"){
      print("found")
    } else {
      print("not found")
}
```